# Problemas con ventana Modal con nodejs

Tags: html, css, nodejs

soy nuevo en nodejs y tengo problema con una ventana modal que contiene un formulario, no captura los datos enviados mediante el boton enviar , no se como obtener esos datos del modal alguien me podría ayudar porfavor  gracias

**Instalacion y declaracion de modulos**

PD: ya están  descargados los modulos en package json de node

```
/*------ -----install module  ----- ------*/
const express = require('express');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const path = require('path');
const morgan = require('morgan');

/*------ ----- Initializations ----- ------*/
const app = express();

/*------ ----- Settings ----- ------*/
//--Port Configuration
app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 3000);
//--View folder Configuration
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
//--Template Settings
app.engine(".hbs",exphbs({
    defaultLayout: "main",
    layoutsDir: path.join(app.get('views'), 'layout'),
    partialsDir: path.join(app.get('views'), 'partials'),
    extname:".hbs"
}));
//--Template view settings
app.set("view engine", ".hbs"),

/*------ ----- Middlewares ----- ------*/
app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json())

/*------ ----- Global  Variables----- ------*/

/*------ ----- Routers ----- ------*/
app.use(require("./routes/index"))
app.use(require("./routes/cliente"))

/*------ ----- Public Folder ----- ------*/

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"public")))
/*------ ----- Starting the Server ----- ------*/
app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log(`The Server on port :${app.get("port")}`);

})
```

**Router cliente**

```
const {Router}=require('express')
const router=Router();

router.get('/add',(req, res) => {
    res.render('Cliente/registro')
});

router.post('/add',(req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send("enviado");
});

module.exports = router;
```

**modal cliente**

Esta es la parte de del modal que contiene el formulario cliente como muestra esta referenciado a la vistas /add con el metodo post , pero no los captura los datos

```
   <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><i
                                class="pci-cross pci-circle"></i></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Client Register</h4>
                    </div>

                    <!--Modal body-->
                    <div class="modal-body">
  <!--form-->
                                    <form class="form-horizontal" action="/add" method="post">
                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="demo-hor-inputemail">Nombre
                                                    :</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre de la Empresa "
                                                        id="demo-hor-inputemail" class="form-control" name="nombre" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Direccion :</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Direccion de la Empresa"
                                                        class="form-control" name="direccion" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" >Ruc :</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Ruc de la Empresa"
                                                       class="form-control" name="ruc" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Telefono :</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Telefono de la Empresa"
                                                        class="form-control" name="telefono" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" >Correo :</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                    <input type="email" placeholder="Correo de la Empresa"
                                                        class="form-control" name="correo" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </form>


 <!--Modal footer-->
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
```

**imagen**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Supongo que el problema es que el botón de tipo sumbit esta fuera del formulario. Yo agregaría los botones dentro de la etiqueta <form>. O mas bien, si quieres dejarlo así como esta, agrégale un Id a la etiqueta <form> y al botón de tipo sumbit agrégale el atributo form con el valor del id de la etiqueta <form>.